# Python webpage login error

Tags: python, html, authentication, cherrypy

I am trying to create create a kind of webserver withy python and cherrypy.

I wish to put the htmls into separate files and embedd them into my python script. The code i used to do that is.

```
    @cherrypy.expose
def welcome(self, loginAttempt = None):
    """ Prompt the user with a login form. The form will be submitted to /signin
        as a POST request, with arguments "username", "password" and "signin"
        Dispaly a login error above the form if there has been one attempted login already.
    """
    #Debugging Process Check
    print "welcome method called with loggedIn = %s" % (loginAttempt)

    if loginAttempt == '1':
       """ If the user has attempted to login once, return the original login page
       with a error message"""
       page = get_file("loginPageE.html") 
       return page

    else:    
        page = """
               <form action='/signin' method='post'>
               Username:  <input type='text' name='username' /> <br />
               Password:  <input type='password' name='password' />
                 <input type='submit' name='signin' value='Sign In'/>
               </form>
        """          
        return page
```

where loginPageE.html is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Failed Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- header-wrap -->
<div id="header-wrap">
    <header>

        <hgroup>
            <h1><a href="loginPageE.html">Acebook</a></h1>
            <h3>Not Just Another Social Networking Site</h3>
        </hgroup>


        <ul>
            <form action='/signin' method='post'>
                Username:  <input type='text' name='username' />
                Password:  <input type='password' name='password' />
                           <input type='submit' name='signin' value='Sign In'/>
            </form>
        </ul>


    </header>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However I keep on getting an error message that reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 606, in respond
    cherrypy.response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 25, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "proj1base.py", line 74, in welcome
    page = get_file("loginPageE.html")
NameError: global name 'get_file' is not defined
```

I was wondering if anyone could please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use a template engine such as [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from the error, evidently python doesn't know what the `get_file()` function is. Are you sure that at that point of time where you invoke this function inside the `welcome()` function, `get_file()` has been defined?

Comment: OF COURSE!! This is totally embarrassing now... I thought something had gone wrong. but instead the function just wasn't declared before the method... Thanks a lot though.

Comment: @AbhranilDas: The second part is just invalid. It just needs to be defined when it's called.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: edited. But are you sure? Because I've written programs with functions that call other functions, and function 2 that uses function 1 fails if function 1 has not been declared before function 2. These functions are called from the main body of the program which starts after all function definitions end. What's the issue then?

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing any code. But it certainly works: http://codepad.org/wQVwnXzI

Answer (score 0):

get_file isn't one of the standard Python functions, so it must be a custom one you used to have. You can create a simple function to read a file and return its contents as a string like this:

```
def get_file(path):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    output = f.read()
    f.close()
    return output
```

You can read up on Python file management at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()
```

However, consider using a proper template engine. [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) is really good and it allows you to use conditionals etc. in templates - something you'll certainly want at some point. Besides that, it does nice things such as variable autoescaping for you if you ask it to.